# VirtualMachine or DualBoot

Tags: 8.1, lumia, apps

Setting up a VM environment to run WinPhone as an emulated OS is easy - but what about the other way around?

Since the architecture of mobile devices is ARM, shouldn't it be possible to dual boot the Device via GRUB (or similar) to use either WinPhone or use the device for other purposes with a mobile unix distribution?

Or, if that won't work without destroying the OS, is there any Emulation software for the phone itself? i heard that MS is working on virtualisation technology to emulate android os...

The background of the question is easy: My win phone has a lot of computing power, which i'd like to harness while i'm not using the phone as intended. Also, i love to play around programming on ARM devices...anyone tried to do something like that before?

---

PS: i can't create tags, but there aren't really tags for this kind of question...

Comment: By "mobile unix distribution" do you mean something like Android?

Comment: More like the raspberry pi distributions, which are optimized for ARM architecture